# How to send JSON data to a Dojo data grid?

Tags: java, json, datagrid, dojo

I had written a JSP page with database connectivity getting the data from the database and printing it JSON format.

And now I want that JSON data to be sent to the Dojo data grid

Here is my JSP code.

```
    <html>
    <head>  
        <script type="text/javascript">
            dojo.require("dojox.data.QueryReadStore");
            dojo.require("dojox.grid._CheckBoxSelector");
            dojo.require("dojo.data.ObjectStore");
            dojo.require("dojo.parser");
            dojo.require("dojox.grid.DataGrid");
            dojo.require("dijit/form/Button");
            dojo.require("dojox/grid/DataGrid");
            dojo.require("dojo/data/ItemFileReadStore");
            dojo.ready(function(){
                mystore=new dojox.data.QueryReadStore({url:"/DojoProject/test"});
                grid = new dojox.grid.DataGrid({
                        store: mystore,
                        structure: [
                            {type: "dojox.grid._CheckBoxSelector",  editable: true},
                           [{name:"id", field:"ID", width: "200px",editable: true},
                            {name:"name", field:"name", width: "200px",editable: true},                         
                            {name:"Result", field:"Result", width: "200px"}]
                        ]}, dojo.byId("gridContainer"));                    
               grid.startup();
            });
        </script>
    <%
        JSONObject responseObj = new JSONObject();
        List<JSONObject> data = new LinkedList<JSONObject>();
        try {
            String dbms = "SQL SERVER"; 
            String serverName = "";
            String portNumber = "1106";
            String userName = "";
            String upassword = "";
            String databaseName = "";
            int datacount = 0;

            //String connectionURL = "jdbc:" + dbms + "://" + sN
            //      + ":" + PN + "/" + databaseN;
            Connection conn = null;
            Class.forName("com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver");
            conn = DriverManager.getConnection("");
            System.out.println("connection::" + conn);

            String strQuery = "select * from sample";
            System.out.println(strQuery);
            PreparedStatement st = conn.prepareStatement(strQuery);
            ResultSet rs = st.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()) {
                datacount++;    
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(); 
                object.put("s1",(String.valueOf(datacount)));
                object.put("ID",rs.getString(1));
                object.put("Name",rs.getString(2));
                System.out.println("ID&name&::"+rs.getString(1) +","+rs.getString(2));
            } 
            responseObj.put("data",data);    
            PrintWriter writer = response.getWriter();                           System.out.println({\"identifier\":\"data\",\"label\":\"data\",\"items\":"+responseObj+"}");       
            writer.write(" "+responseObj+"");        
            writer.flush();
            writer.close();    
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);  
        }  %>  

    <head>
    <body class="claro">
        <div id="some">
            <div id="gridContainer" style="width: 100%; height: 200px;">
            <button data-dojo-type="dijit/form/Button" type="submit" name="submitButton" value="Submit">Submit</button> </div>   
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Here, I am getting the data from the database in the JSON format as following:

```
{"data":[{"sl":"1","id":"1","name":"shivasrinat"}
{"data":[{"sl":"1","id":"1","name":"shivasrinat"}
```

Answer (score 0):

The QueryReadStore needs the data from JSP on a specific JSON format, otherwise it doesn't know what to do with it.

Take a look at the very last line of the [sample PHP implementation](https://github.com/dojo/dojox/blob/master/data/tests/stores/QueryReadStore.php) for a QueryReadStore backend:

```
print '/*'.json_encode(array('numRows'=>$numRows, 'items'=>$ret, 'identity'=>'id')).'*/';
```

It's not so different from your format, but you see it requires 3 specific keys: numRows, items and identity. You only have one: data. So try changing your JSP to output something like this:

```
{"numRows":42, "identity":"id", "items": [{"sl":"1","id":"1","name":"shivasrinat"}] }
```

The `numRows` attribute should be the total number of items available that matches the query (because sometimes you only want to retrieve a small amount, not the entire database).

Comment: thanks.but i need this json format need to store dojo datagrid.